# Buy products from or buy products on amazon

Tags: prepositions

Does "buy" verb has dependent preposition or you just apply appropriate preposition?

> You can buy products **from** amazon (website)
>
> You can buy products **on** amazon (website)

Which is correct?

Comment: There are also several other possible prepositions, including *at*, *using*, *with*, and *through*.

Comment: from amazon (the company), on amazon (the website). Both are valid but don't mean the same thing. The verb is not involved.